# Scrape headlines with Playwright, how to write output into Markdown file (Console.log is working)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, markdown, playwright

So I want to scrape some headlines of a website and use them on my website(managed with markdown files).
The script works and output is looks fine in the console. But I am not able to write the value of the 'For loop' to the markdown file.

Have tried to use the whole object and place the variable name(  ${list} ) in the markdown, also tried to write single nodes of the output to the markdown( ${firstItem} ).
Been searching for 'write result javascript to markdown', 'print object to markdown', 'convert json to markdown', have looked into strings, and tried a couple of related terms but no result so far.

If you have a tip or know a way to solve this, sharing it is very much appreciated.

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true, slowMo: 250 });
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page90 = await browser.newPage();

await page90.goto("https://books.toscrape.com/");
const listcontent = await page90.evaluate(() => {
const data = [];

const books = document.querySelectorAll(".product_pod");
books.forEach((book) => {
  let title = book.querySelector('.thumbnail').getAttribute("alt");
  let url = book.querySelector('a').getAttribute("href");
  data.push({
    title,
    url,
  });
});
return data;
});

// console.log(listcontent);
// listcontent.forEach(item => console.log(item))
// [listcontent].forEach(console.log, console);
// [listcontent].forEach(console.log.bind(console));
// let list = {};

for (const {title: n, url: f} of listcontent) {
console.log('[' + n + '](' + f + ')');
// return list;
}

//  let firstItem = listcontent[0]
// lists as json
console.log(listcontent)

// for (const property of listcontent) {
//   console.log(`${property}: ${url[property]}`);
// }


// ${firstItem} 
// ${list}

// Create Markdown with frontmatter part:
fs.promises.writeFile(`file` + '.md', `---

---

`);

console.log('MD created');
await browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you script is missing some brackets and braces, so this one is valid:

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page90 = await browser.newPage();

  await page90.goto("https://books.toscrape.com/");
  const listcontent = await page90.evaluate(() => {
    const data = [];

    const books = document.querySelectorAll(".product_pod");
      books.forEach((book) => {
        let title = book.querySelector('.thumbnail').getAttribute("alt");
        let url = book.querySelector('a').getAttribute("href");
        data.push({
          title,
          url,
        });
      });
      return data;
  });  
  
  browser.close();

})();
```

The easies way to save text into a file in a markdown style is to build a string in a particular format and then dump it into a file:

```js
let string = '';
for (const {title: n, url: f} of listcontent) {
  string += '[' + n + '](' + f + ')\n\n';
}
```

and then write it into a file:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('books.md', string);
```

if you want an asynchronous function:

```js
fs.writeFile('books.md', string, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("File was saved.");
  browser.close();
});
```

So the whole script:

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page90 = await browser.newPage();

  await page90.goto("https://books.toscrape.com/");
  const listcontent = await page90.evaluate(() => {
    const data = [];

    const books = document.querySelectorAll(".product_pod");
      books.forEach((book) => {
        let title = book.querySelector('.thumbnail').getAttribute("alt");
        let url = book.querySelector('a').getAttribute("href");
        data.push({
          title,
          url,
        });
      });
      return data;
  });

  let string = '';
  for (const {title: n, url: f} of listcontent) {
    string += '[' + n + '](' + f + ')\n\n';
  }

  /*fs.writeFile('books.md', string, function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("File was saved.");
    browser.close();
  });*/

  fs.writeFileSync('books.md', string);
  browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: Wow thanks Pavel! This is working. Still need some Frontmatter at the top of the markdown file, but think I can fix that.